# Doctrine entity mapping incorrect

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have just created a new entity called ProductReviews which contains the following two joins.

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Products
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Products", inversedBy="reviews")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id")
 * })
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Users
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Users", inversedBy="reviews")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

in my Products entity I have

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ProductReviews", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="product")
 */
private $reviews;
```

and finally in my Users entity I have

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ProductReviews", mappedBy="user")
 * })
 */
private $reviews;
```

When I go to validate my entities I get the following error

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Application\Entity\ProductReviews' mapping is invalid:

- The association Application\Entity\ProductReviews#product refers to the inverse side field Application\Entity\Products#reviews which does not exist.
- The association Application\Entity\ProductReviews#user refers to the inverse side field Application\Entity\Users#reviews which does not exist.

However both the inverse side fields exist and as far as I can tell are mapped correctly.

Can anyone spot what I have done wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.  The problem was caused by Doctrines cache, by clearing it the entities now map correctly.

I used the following command line commands to clear the cache.

```
php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:query
php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:metadata
php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:result
```

and the following to check the entities mapping.

```
php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
```

I hope this helps someone out.